# fetch contact and from contact check who is using this app just like WhatsApp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter

I am using flutter and node.js and mongodb as database i want to fetch contact and check who is using my app just like WhatsApp.
On flutter i am using flutter_contacts package
All users's phone numbers are stored in mongodb database
how do i check that how many of my contact are on my app.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the contacts of the user and create an index in MongoDB for mobile number by using the Mongoose `find()` method to match the mobile number in the query and if the number exists in your database display it to the user about the information

Please provide more detailed information.

You can use find method here :

```
 model.find({phone:mobile_number})
```

Here you are matching the phone number to check if it exists

or you can use `findOne()` function in same manner too.